# trying to understand condition variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I have read about condition variables to signal between two or more threads. Now I am trying to understand some code I have. I have (simplified):

```
class Class{
    void put(Something&& something){
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(a_mutex);
            // Do the operation here
            some_operation();
        }
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }
    
    std::unique_ptr<Something> get(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(a_mutex);
   
        cond_var.wait(lock,[this]{return someCondition()});
    
        //Do the operation here
        auto res=some_other_operation();
        return res;
    }
    
    std::mutex a_mutex;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;    
};
```

I can understand that `put` acquires a lock and do some operation and then notifies any thread waiting to unblock. Also `get` blocks until the condition variable gets signaled by put or it blocks if `someCondition` is not true. Once it gets signaled it do some other operation and returns its value.

What I don't understand is the timing.

For example let's say that the `put` function is called and it notifies but no thread is waiting because `get` has not been called. What happens?

Then let's say `get` gets called and it blocks. Or it doesn't? (ideally it *shouldn't* because someone already called `put` first).

Should `get` wait until `put` is called *again*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example let's say that the put function is called and it notifies
>   but no thread is waiting because get has not been called. What
>   happens?

docs says: *If any threads are waiting on *this, calling notify_one unblocks one of the waiting threads.* **If any**, then if no nothing special happens.

> Then let's say get gets called and it blocks. Or it doesn't?? (ideally
>   it shouldn't because someone already called put first).

It will be blocked conditionally to `someCondition()`. If `someOperation()` leads to `someCondition()` being realized then `wait` will be unblocked when `notify_one()` will be called, or not blocked at all if `someCondition()` is already realized.

Comment: thanks. I am digesting your explanation:) especially the last paragraph. So correct me if I am wrong... it will *not get blocked* if `someCondition()` is true?? That makes sense...

Comment: Exactly. If you call wait and the condition is true then you will not release the lock, not wait and continue immediately... If you call wait and the condition is false, then you release the lock, placed on a wait queue until someone else calls notify and at this time you will retest the condition, etc.

Comment: so that is where I am getting it wrong. `wait` release the lock and is placed on a wait queue only if the condition is false?   (by the way I have a related question)

Comment: With that being said, and this being multithreaded, what happens if put and get are called almost simultaneously?  I suppose there the mutex is involved

Comment: @KansaiRobot that is the purpose of the mutex to ensure that only one gets it, the other one being blocked.